# @BeanParam does not work with Apache CXF 3.0.x

Tags: apache, rest, jakarta-ee, cxf, jax-rs

I am trying to use @BeanParam annotation from JAX-RS.

It was working perfectly fine with Apache cxf 2.7.7 but after upgrading to Apache cxf 3.0.1 it does not work. In my rest  service, bean param is null and i get NullPointerException.

I have tried with cxf 3.0.3 but result is same.

My RestService looks like

```
Class MyService {
    @BeanParam
    private MyBean params;

    @Path("/test")
    public Response testIt() {
        // params is null here
    }
}

class MyBean {
   @QueryParam
   private String message;

   public void setMessage(String message) {
       this.message = message;
   }

   public String getMessage() {
       return this.message;
   }
}
```

My dependency in gradle looks like

```
def cxfVersion = "3.0.1"

ext.libraries = [

cxf: [
    "org.apache.cxf:apache-cxf:$cxfVersion",
    "org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:$cxfVersion"
]
```

Does anybody have any idea what has changed form cxf 2.7.7 to cxf 3.0.x, that will make this non functioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was due to presence of another cxf version jar present on classpath (version 2.3.3) coming from other projects dependencies. Somehow that was getting the precedence over 3.x version and that didn't had support for BeanParam.

Removing that jar from classpath worked for me.